# Flow and Immutable.js Map

Tags: javascript, immutable.js, flowtype

I'm new to Flow, and I'm trying to figure out how to get it to work with Immutable JS's Map.

I have the following code:-

```
// @flow

import { Map } from 'immutable';

let myMap: Map<string, number> = new Map({ a: 'a' });

myMap = myMap.merge({ a: 'a' });
```

When I run Flow, I get the following error, which is expected:-

```
src/js/a.js:7
  7: myMap = myMap.merge({ a: 'a' });
                              ^^^ string. This type is incompatible with
  5: let myMap: Map<string, number> = Map({ a: 'a' });
                            ^^^^^^ number
```

My question is why `new Map({ a: 'a' });` is not marked as error?

Is it possible to make that as an error? In my existing project that I'm trying to apply Flow on, we have a lot of similar usage and it will be nice if Flow can enforce type check on that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I'm learning flow too, but that seems like a bug. The flow declaration for Immutable's Map class looks like this:

```
declare class Map<K,V> extends KeyedCollection<K,V> {
  static <K, V>(): Map<K, V>;
  static <V>(obj?: {[key: string]: V}): Map<string, V>;
  ...
```

Interestingly,

```
const mapIngredients: { [string]: number } = { a: 'a' }
```

*does* trigger a flow error on 'a'. It seems like something is going wrong when flow typechecks the argument to `Map`. Indeed, even `Map(123)` typechecks :/

flow version: 0.37.4